# How to can I make Filename Sequencing with the help of Loops

Tags: shell-script, files, awk, wildcards

my intention is to keep the code as simple as possible.Here there are 5 files namely

`A_1.CSV, A_2.CSV, A_3.CSV, A_4.CSV, A_5.CSV`

The below code retrieves the first row in a CSV file.

Code : head.sh(filename)

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print $0}' A_1.CSV > Header.csv
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print $0}' A_2.CSV >> Header.csv
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print $0}' A_3.CSV >> Header.csv
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print $0}' A_4.CSV >> Header.csv
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print $0}' A_5.CSV >> Header.csv
```

Question :

In the above code, only the filename changes from A_1 to A_2 and so on. How can I make the code simple with loops.

Example :

```
 for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
      {
       A_[i].CSV >> Header.csv
      }
```

I don't know how to do this logic with shell scripting.

UPDATED CODE :

Files in the Directory :
/home/thiyagu/Desktop/

```
for file in 'A_*.CSV'
do
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print $0}' $file >> Newheader.csv
done
```

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
 awk 'FNR==1' A_*.csv > Header.csv
```

where

- `FNR` is File Number Record
- default action is to print the while line
- I dropped `-F,` as you don't care about individual field (If you have other thing to do, however, you can add it back)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this will work:

```
for file in `ls A_*.csv`
do
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print $0}' $file >> Header.csv
done
```

This is basic shell scripting looping. You can find these tutorials online, if you search for them.

Comment: Edit, as @jasonwryan pointed out in your previous post, you do not even need the {print $0}.

Comment: There is no point in using `ls` here. You can just say `for file in A_*.csv`.

Comment: @camh @rahul yup `ls` is not needed. I am getting the result just for one file. In the Header.csv, I can find only one row. But, I need it for multiple files(i.e 5 rows).

Comment: @Thiyagu are you sure you are pointing to the correct files? I tested this for two files (A_1.csv, A_2.csv) and it extracted the header from both the files and placed them in Header.csv. Are your source files in different directories? Or did you use '>' instead of '>>' . The first will overwrite and the second will append.

Comment: @rahul The files are in the same directory. I used append (>>). I don't know why it shows only one row.

Comment: @rahul it just takes the header of the first file. The rest its not appending.

Comment: @Thiyagu can you paste the code and listing contents of the directory here? Maybe there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: @rahul Kindly look in the code under the subheading "UPDATED CODE ".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21669/discussion-between-rahul-and-thiyagu).

Comment: @Thiyagu I'm having some problems logging into chat, but i figured out the problem. Please remove the ''. Instead of for file in 'A_*.CSV', use for file in A_*.CSV .

Comment: great. It works fine. Why is that so. What difference it makes ?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score -1):

Single quotes prevent expansion: every character in a single-quoted string is interpreted literally (except `'` itself which ends the string). So when you want `*` to act as a wildcard, leave it outside the quotes. (Double quotes also prevent `*` from acting as a wildcard.)

```
for file in A_*.CSV …
```

The rest of your updated code is probably ok, but you should [put double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), otherwise sooner or later it will bite you.

You can take the redirection outside the loop. This is slightly faster.

```
for file in A_*.CSV
do
  awk -F, 'NR==1 {print $0}' "$file"
done >> Newheader.csv
```

This snippet appends to `Newheader.csv`. If you want to overwrite the file when it already exists, like in your original code, replace `>>` by `>`.

There are several ways to simplify your script, if all you want is to print the first line of several files. Since you're just printing the first line, `-F,` isn't used. Furthermore you could use `head -n 1` instead of `awk 'NR == 1 {print $0}'`. On Linux (but not on all Unix variants), to print just the first line of several files, you can use `head` without any loop:

```
head -q -n 1 A_*.CSV >Newheader.csv
```

You also don't need a loop with awk, see [Archemar's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188313).